# Array sort by compare to string

Tags: php, sorting, autocomplete

Is it possible to sort an array by comparing all values to a chosen string?

I am trying to sort some autocomplete results to have `"like%"` before those with `"%like%"`.

Comment: Have you tried two different queries with an UNION ?

Comment: i use the same query for other filds

Comment: @Rastaking, could you give some sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: What I meant is to do `(SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'test%') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%test%' WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM table WHERE field LIKE 'test%'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use usort with a closure and similar text.

```
$word = "targetword";
usort($matches, function ($a, $b) use ($word) {
     return similar_text($word,$a) - similar_text($word, $b);
});
```

Comment: i didn't find how to add the $word variable :)  ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is function called [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) which returns an integer describing the similarity of 2 strings. You can easily create a referential array with that similarity value as an index and hand this array over to [ksort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).